# Calling functions by ng-change event based on particular condition angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-change

I have two dropdowns 1.FamilyDropdown 2.Class Dropdown. First both are populating different item list at time of page load. I have created a table where that two dropdowns are connected by their respective Ids.

Problem: 1. I am doing both side dependent dropdown means if i change family dropdown first then class dropdown will populate respective items.

2. If i change Class dropdown first then Family dropdown will populate respective items.
3. i have tried two different ng-change event function for these two models. But change event is continuously executing. How to put condition to execute particular ng-change event.

I will submit the code here if needed

Comment: ng-change fires when the model is updated it's not a regular JS event it's capturing like ng-click or ng-mouseover it is tied to the ngModel and just uses the ngModel controller to know when to trigger the function, that said no reason it shouldn't work in this scenario and don't see why it would be "continuously executing" please show a running example (here plnkr, jsfiddle, codepen anywhere works).  Also not a technical issue really but I don't think this makes for a very clear user interface in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes ng-change is calling the function when ever the dropdown change. Is there any different approach to do that Populating dropdown items based on others. When i change First dropdown item  after page load second dropdown will populate item. If i change 2nd dropdown after page load 1st will populate based on 2nd.

Comment: Think ng-change really is the typical way to go about it hence being a bit confused on what you're running into here.

Comment: I am not using plunker or jsFiddle. I am newbie here. Please give me some suggestions or help on this question.

Comment: Just go here https://next.plnkr.co/edit/tpl:SVvaUX modify the html/js/css to show minimal reproduction of your problem in action and hit the save button, it will update the URL then share that URL in the comments here, hit the play button to see a live preview of your code changes as you update things.  If I or others can see problems there it is 100x faster to solve typically.

Comment: Thanks Shaun. Yes I will try to update my problem there.  Thank you for helping